# Pulling portfolio from bloomberg

Tags: python, bloomberg, excel

I am not sure wether I should post this question here or on stack overflow, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

I am trying to get my portfolio from PORT in bloomberg. Basically I am trying to automate a process where the prtofolio is extracted and then emailed. The issue is that i do not have an internal file with the different positions and sizes, it is only on Bloomberg. So I cannot rebuil the protfolio. Formatting and emailing is not an issue but I do not see how to get data from PORT. I first checked through excel unsuccessfully then I tried with the python API vut the documentation is quite limited so I could not find what I was looking for. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: btw I am not very experimented with bloomberg. i am used to programming but not so much with bloomberg

Comment: As far as I know, you can only extract it manually from the PORT holdings screen. Probably worth confirming with Bloomberg help desk. I'd be interested to know the answer you get.

Comment: great thanks. I'll try to confirm with them and let you know. It is definitely something that should be added to API. I'll probably suggest it ob github. I am sure some one more gifted than me will find a solution

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this response is useful for OP after 2 years. But in case anyone is searching for solution:

```
refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
request = refDataService.createRequest("PortfolioDataRequest")
request.append("securities", "UXXXXXXXX-XX Client")
request.append("fields", "PORTFOLIO_DATA")
session.sendRequest(request)
```

The createRequest() should use the parameter "PortfolioDataRequest".
For more see documentation of C++ BLPAPI: The Python API is just a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use the Python API, but I am sure you can retrieve PORT data via the API. In R, with package `Rblpapi`, you could say

```
library("Rblpapi")
blpConnect()
getPortfolio("<Portfolio ID>", "PORTFOLIO_DATA")
```

and receive the portfolio as a data frame. The `<Portfolio ID>` you see in `PRTU`; you may need to append the word `client`.

Comment: Great thank you very much.  I just saw your answer. Maybe I will use R then.